How to authenticate from Frappe using Cross Site Frontend App with Session?
I've been working on the front-end app using Vue3. I want to integrate this frontend with Frappe Framework. T
here is a CORS error while working with Frappe's authentication system. The CORS error was resolved in development mode, but in production it still gives an error.
I was wondering about the authentication using Frappe API /api/method/login.
This error occurs when I try to login using API.

This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because it had the "SameSite=Lax" attribute but came from a cross-site origin which was not the response to a top level navigation. This response is considered cross-site because the URL has a different scheme than the current site

But the situation is when I make the request to the server, it returns OK 200. But the session is not sent back to the client side, so I can manage the session. Please try to help me out.
How can I manage the session and proceed other API workloads using the same session and after that I can proceed to check whether the user is logged in or not and logout?

Is this a question about the CORS or about the session? Please keep in mind that questions on SO should focus on one specific problem at the time - [ask]. Furthermore, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Yes it is. But it is specific with Frappe Framework. That's why.

Yes it's what? Please revise your question so it's about one specific problem
